# Upper bound of Sine Kernel

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

How can I show that the upper bound (spectral radius) of the Sine kernel is 1, i.e. $|\lambda_{max}|\le1$?
$$K(x,y)=\frac{\text{sin}\{\pi(x-y)\}}{\pi(x-y)}$$
The corresponding integral equation is,
$$\lambda\psi(x)=\int_{-s/2}^{s/2}K(x,y)\psi (y)dy$$

Comment: Have you considered the fact that $\left\lvert \frac{\sin(u)}{u}\right\rvert\leq 1$ for all $u\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$?

Comment: what is the value of $s$?

Comment: @robjohn, $s\in (-\infty,\infty)$.

Comment: @MichaelLee, that's fine for this particular kernel. How about an arbitrary kernel?